# How can I set values to PagerParameter parameter in Controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

I am trying to send PagerParameter property values as JSON to the controller action. But both the properties are ending up as Null. My objective is  to implement infinitescrolling feature with paginated data. The scrolling part is working fine, controller is also giving records back to me, but not paginated - all data!

Because the PagerParameter object values are Null. Below is what I am trying to do.

```
public ActionResult DisplayPaged(string subjectPath, PagerParameters pagerParameters)
{
...
...
}
```

And this is how I am sending the values from my AJAX method in the View:

```
$.ajax({
url: "@Url.Action(actionName: "DisplayPaged", controllerName: "Question")",
data: { 'subjectPath': 'lending', pagerParameters: { 'Page': pageCounter, 'PageSize': 2 } },
...
...
});
```

But both pagerParameter.Page and pagerParameter.PageSize properties are null.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to send them as JSON. Instead, do a post that respects ASP.NET MVC conventions for naming form fields, such as "pagerParameters.Page": pageCounter.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?